# Como utilizar a API do Youtube?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube, youtube-api

Tenho uma pagina com um video que abre num modal, preciso que ele fique pausado quando o modal estiver ocultado.
Testei exemplos que encontrei em outros sites mas não funcionou.

Preciso adicionar algum arquivo extra para utilizar o control da API?

Comment: Como você está incorporando o vídeo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei como você está fechando o seu modal, mas se vc está utilizando `.hide()` do jQuery, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
function pause_video(){
    $('#youtube_iframe_id')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
}

function hideCallBack() { 
    pause_video()
}
```

Com as duas funções adicionadas no seu código, seu vídeo será pausado quando você fechar o modal usando:

```
$('#modal_id').hide(hideCallBack);
```